# How to get the top rows from a dataframe with multiple columns set as the index?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that has two columns 'sp' and 'bg' set as the index and is sorted by 'score'. I would like to get the top two rows for each 'sp' value in the dataframe

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([
    {'sp': 'A', 'bg': 'a', 'score': 1234},
    {'sp': 'A', 'bg': 'b', 'score': 123},
    {'sp': 'A', 'bg': 'c', 'score': 12},
    {'sp': 'A', 'bg': 'd', 'score': 1},
    {'sp': 'B', 'bg': 'a', 'score': 234},
    {'sp': 'B', 'bg': 'b', 'score': 23},
    {'sp': 'C', 'bg': 'a', 'score': 345},
    {'sp': 'C', 'bg': 'b', 'score': 34},
    {'sp': 'C', 'bg': 'c', 'score': 3},
])

df.set_index(['sp', 'bg'], inplace=True)
```

Output should be a dataframe:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([
    {'sp': 'A', 'bg': 'a', 'score': 1234},
    {'sp': 'A', 'bg': 'b', 'score': 123},
    {'sp': 'B', 'bg': 'a', 'score': 234},
    {'sp': 'B', 'bg': 'b', 'score': 23},
    {'sp': 'C', 'bg': 'a', 'score': 345},
    {'sp': 'C', 'bg': 'b', 'score': 34},
])

df.set_index(['sp', 'bg'], inplace=True)
```

Comment: `df.groupby('sp').head(2)` possibly sort first if it's not already. There's a dup somewhere

Comment: If your data was *unsorted*, use `df.groupby(level='sp')['score'].nlargest(2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    {'sp': 'A', 'bg': 'a', 'score': 1234},
    {'sp': 'A', 'bg': 'b', 'score': 123},
    {'sp': 'A', 'bg': 'c', 'score': 12},
    {'sp': 'A', 'bg': 'd', 'score': 1},
    {'sp': 'B', 'bg': 'a', 'score': 234},
    {'sp': 'B', 'bg': 'b', 'score': 23},
    {'sp': 'C', 'bg': 'a', 'score': 345},
    {'sp': 'C', 'bg': 'b', 'score': 34},
    {'sp': 'C', 'bg': 'c', 'score': 3},
])

df.set_index(['sp', 'bg'], inplace=True)

df = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('sp').score.nlargest(2)).droplevel(0)

print(df)
```

The output of which is:

```
       score
sp bg       
A  a    1234
   b     123
B  a     234
   b      23
C  a     345
   b      34
```